# Magento 1.9.2.1: which js is conflicting and causes not showing up the checkout onepage?

Tags: javascript, magento

This is the console screenshot of my chekcout/onepage :- [image]I have included jquery.min.js in page.xml under head and in my checkout/onepage.phtml contains

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('varien/accordion.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout_rwd.js') ?>"></script>
```

N.B: Removing any of the opcheckout.js also not working I have tried removing that already.

Login Checkout shipping info billing info form in not showing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by jQuery overwriting the "$" variable that prototype uses. To fix it you just have to call this code right after loading jQuery:

```
var varname = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Where varname is your replacement for jQuery's "$" variable (I personally use $j). If you had any other jQuery code you'll have to modify it to use this new variable instead of $.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Its not overwritten.